# Can we get same instance of ViewModel inside parent Activity when we use navGraphViewModels?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-navigation, android-navigationview, android-navigation-graph

I have a fragment container view to load more than three fragments, each fragment shared by ViewModel using navGraphViewModels

```
private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.home_navigation_xml) { defaultViewModelProviderFactory }
```

How can we get the same instance of ViewModel inside parent activity?

Comment: Why are you using a navigation graph scoped view model if you want to access it at a larger scope (i.e., the whole activity level)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following method to solve my issue.

```
val viewModel by lazy {
            binding?.homeFragmentContainerView?.findNavController()
                ?.getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.home_navigation_xml)?.viewModelStore?.let {
                    ViewModelProvider(
                        it,
                        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
                    ).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
                }
        }
```